BigQuery count rows between values
I am struggling on what I thought was a simple request from a user.
The intended output would be to count the number of calls made before a certain value appears (in this example 'PTP').
My current query is as follows:
 SELECT
    calls.source_id AS customer_id,
    calls.rdate AS call_datetime,
    calls.outbound_log_id AS calls_id, 
    CASE 
      WHEN dispo.q_code_grouping_desc = 'PTP' 
      THEN 'PTP' 
      ELSE 'NO PTP'
    END AS ptp_ind,
    CASE
      WHEN dispo.q_code_grouping_desc = 'PTP' 
      THEN 0
      ELSE 1
      END AS calls_made_before

  FROM db.prepared_layers.outbound_log AS calls
  LEFT JOIN db.latest_dim.outbound_service_dm AS service
    ON service.id = calls.service_id
  LEFT JOIN db.latest_dim.outbound_dispo_all AS dispo
    ON dispo.code = calls.q_code
    AND dispo.service_id = calls.service_id
  WHERE service.service_type_dept = 'collections' 
  AND DATE(rdate) >= '2024-06-01'
  AND calls.source_id IN (1600, 1601)
  
  ORDER BY source_id, rdate ASC

I have tried various ROW_NUMBER(), LEAD(), and LAG() functions, but without any luck.
Below is a sample table of what I am trying to achieve:

I basically need to count the rows (calls) before each instance of 'PTP' under the ptp_ind field. The count should reset after each occurrence.
My attempt using row_number() only gets the first occurrence correct, there after I am not resetting the count correctly I feel:
WITH seq_grp AS (
  SELECT
    calls.source_id,
    calls.rdate,
    calls.outbound_log_id,
    CASE 
      WHEN dispo.q_code_grouping_desc = 'PTP' 
      THEN 'PTP' 
      ELSE 'NO PTP'
    END AS ptp_ind,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dispo.q_code_grouping_desc = 'PTP' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
      OVER (PARTITION BY calls.source_id ORDER BY calls.rdate ASC) AS grp
  FROM `db.prepared_layers.outbound_log` calls
  LEFT JOIN `db.latest_dim.outbound_service_dm` service
    ON service.id = calls.service_id
  LEFT JOIN `db.latest_dim.outbound_dispo_all` dispo
    ON dispo.code = calls.q_code
    AND dispo.service_id = calls.service_id
  WHERE service.service_type_dept = 'collections' 
  AND DATE(rdate) >= '2024-06-01'
  AND calls.source_id IN (1600, 1601)
),

seq_grp_2 AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY source_id, grp ORDER BY rdate ASC) AS rn
  FROM seq_grp
)

SELECT
  * EXCEPT(grp, rn),
  LAG(rn) OVER (PARTITION BY source_id ORDER BY rdate ASC) AS calls_made_before
FROM seq_grp_2
ORDER BY source_id, rdate ASC

Anyone know how to get this right?

This looks like a gaps and islands problem.

Your sample query has additional columns not explained. Also didn't indicate if the count is to be by customer. Answer below assumes minimum required to get expected results, based on the structure made in the first query, and assuming count is by customer as shown in second query.

Query steps:

Add numeric boolean columns for current row PTP value and previous row PTP value, partitioned by customer_id and ordered by call_datetime, call_id. This will be used for getting the cumulative count.
If the previous row was PTP run a cumulative counter, otherwise reset it. Note, the counter would appear on all rows till No PTP appears.
Clean up the counter column for rows that are not No PTP


WITH base AS (
  SELECT
    customer_id,
    call_datetime,
    call_id,
    ptp_ind,
    -- Check if the current row is a PTP
    CASE 
      WHEN ptp_ind = 'PTP' THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END AS is_ptp,
    -- Check if the previous row was a PTP
    LAG(CASE WHEN ptp_ind = 'PTP' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY call_datetime, call_id) AS prev_is_ptp
  FROM 
    source_table
),
counter AS (
  SELECT
    customer_id,
    call_datetime,
    call_id,
    ptp_ind,
    is_ptp,
    prev_is_ptp,
    -- Calculate a cumulative sum that resets when the current or previous row is a PTP
    SUM(CASE WHEN prev_is_ptp = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY call_datetime, call_id) AS calls_made_before_ptp
  FROM 
    base
)
SELECT
  customer_id,
  call_datetime,
  call_id,
  ptp_ind,
  -- Only show the cumulative count on rows where no PTP appears
  CASE 
    WHEN ptp_ind = 'NO PTP' THEN calls_made_before_ptp
    ELSE NULL
  END AS calls_made_before_ptp
FROM 
  counter
ORDER BY 
  customer_id,
  call_datetime,
  call_id;


